# Can i call a action in every 20 second inside a timer which is always running in every second

Tags: javascript

I need to print a console in every 20 second(technically i will call a action in reactjs) inside a interval which is running in every second.
this is a dummy code not functioning properly.

```
var intervalDuration = 200;
    var hitOnEvery = 20;
    setInterval(() => {
         interValDuration -= 1;
          if (interValDuration >= 0) {
            setTimeout(()=>{
                console.log(interValDuration , 'Hit on every' + hitOnEvery + 'second')
            },hitOnEvery);
          } 
       console.log('This will print every '+intervalDuration +'count in a place')
    }, 1000);
```

can someone correct and help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```js
var interValDuration = 200;
    var hitOnEvery = 20;
    setInterval(() => {
         interValDuration -= 1;
          if (interValDuration % hitOnEvery == 0) {
                console.log(interValDuration , 'Hit on every' + hitOnEvery + 'second')
          } 
       console.log('This will print every '+interValDuration +'count in a place')
    }, 1000);
```

Basically check if `interValDuration` divided by `hitOnEvery` has 0 leftover after division, meaning every 20sec perform action

Answer (score 0):

Here is the closure function, for the generic usage

```js
const timer = (() => {
  let timer;
  let seconds = 1;
  return (func, hitAtTime) => {
    let stopTimer = () => {
      console.log(timer);
      window.clearInterval(timer);
    };
    const startTimer = () => {
      timer = window.setInterval(() => {
        console.log("i run every second");
        seconds++;
        if (seconds % hitAtTime === 0) {
          func();
        }
      }, 1000);
    };
    return {
      stopTimer: stopTimer,
      startTimer: startTimer,
    };
  };
})();

timer(() => console.log("i run every 10 seconds"), 10).startTimer();
```